# В std::filesystem в c++17 string или char*

Tags: c++, файловая-система, c++17

Собственно, есть код:

```
if (!std::filesystem::exists(mes)) std::filesystem::create_directories(mes);
```

Какого формата должен быть *mes*?

std::string или char*

Comment: Ни то, ни другое https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Какого формата должен быть mes? std::string или char*

Там широкий выбор возможностей:

1. Указатель `char *`:

   ```
   std::filesystem::exists(std::filesystem::path(mes));
   ```
2. Расширение предыдущего варианта: итератор в начале нуль-терминированной строки:

   ```
   // `\0` подставляется автоматически:
   std::filesystem::exists(std::filesystem::path(mes.c_str()));

   // `\0` надо вставлять в строку вручную:
   std::filesystem::exists(std::filesystem::path(mes.begin()));
   ```
3. Пара итераторов, задающих начало и конец строки:

   ```
   std::filesystem::exists(std::filesystem::path(mes.begin(), mes.end()));
   ```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: Вообще-то во всех трех предложенных вариантах передается `std::filesystem::path`, а преобразование `std::string` или `char *` в `std::filesystem::path` таким образом чревато. *"`\0` надо вставлять в строку вручную"* - это тоже неверно, как и использование одного итератора в надежде, что это просто указатель.

Comment: @VTT `во всех трех предложенных вариантах передается std::filesystem::path` — согласен, но это всего лишь обёртка; пользователь метода в конечном счёте всё равно передаёт либо сишную строку, либо std::string.

Comment: Ну нет, передача сишной строки или `std::string` - это практически всегда грубая ошибка (причем даже если `filesystem::path` сам хранит путь в виде`std::string`). Преобразование сишной строки или `std::string` в `filesystem::path` - дело нетривиальное.